# Specifying a network interface for a cifs (samba) drive

Tags: networking, ip, samba, vpn, cifs

Is it possible to mount a cifs drive using a specific interface?

My scenario is that I have a vpn connection (`tun0`) and I have my normal internet connection (`eth0`). I can only access the shared drive via the vpn, however I would like to use my normal connection with everything else.

Is this possible?

Edit;
After some further research, I've found that this question is way harder to answer that I thought it would be. I tried to start a separate namespace (`ip netns add`), then move the vpn connection in there (`ip link tun0 set netns`). This did not work as `tun0` could couldn't find `eth0` to use (as it is in the root namespace).

I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2):

You can. There are various routing tricks (you can mark outgoing packets with iptables to use alternative routing tables), but you don't need it.

You need only 2 important things:

1. Don't allow the VPN to override your default route. It depends on your VPN software, how can you do it. If nothing works, you can manually remove the default route and set to your original one (`ip route del default; ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0` or so). From that point, only your communication will go on the VPN what targets specifically IP addresses listening on your VPN ip segments.
2. Mount the remote share using the IP of the server inside the VPN (`smbmount '\\192.168.173.5\SecretDocuments' /mnt/public` or so).

Also you can configure samba to listen only your vpn interface, but your case doesn't need also that.